# regression with percentage DV and multiple dummy IV

Tags: regression, percentage, ratio, cross-section, marketing

I am running a market analysis about e-mail responses for my marketing class.

I have the following data entries:

Observations: 400 different sequences of e-mails where sent to different target groups. Each sequence has a different number of delivered emails (from a batch of 18 to 70 e-mails), each has a different reply rate, number of positive answers, and conversion rate.

I have the following dummy variables:

1. Country of focus (i.e. 5 different countries where e-mails are sent)
2. Different call to actions (i.e. call, appointment, demonstration)
3. 1 external factor (i.e. holiday or normal working day)
4. Seniority level of the target (i.e. management, employee, intern)

**I want to know which IV may/may not have an impact on the number of positive replies and conversion rate.**

After numerous readings and videos, I did not find an answer about how to run regression using percentage dependent variable(s) and multiple dummies.

*Note1: Reply/delivered are defined as percentage of number of delivered emails (i.e. 5% out of 35 delivered emails)
Note2: Reply rates are defined as percentage of total number of replies (i.e. 1.47% of all replies are for sequence 15 out of 19 sequences)*

See an excerpt of data in attached file.

[image: first 19 sequences]

Comment: Do you *only* have percentages? or do you have the numerator/denominator? It would be better to use data in the last form, then maybe poisson regression with $\log(\text{denominator})$ as an offset.  Search this site for [tag:poisson-regression].

Comment: If you have numerator and denominator, then binomial regression.  If not, fractional logistic regression, or, if there are no 0 or 100% response rates, beta regression.  But you can find more discussion elsewhere on CV.